# Cassandra cpp-driver compile error

Tags: c++, linux, ubuntu, cassandra

I'm trying to install Cassandra cpp-driver in Ubuntu.
I've done the steps specified in [DataStax C/C++ Driver for Apache Cassandra (Beta)](https://github.com/datastax/cpp-driver), but i keep getting the following compile error.

---

`[  1%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/cassandra.dir/src/buffer_collection.cpp.o
In file included from /root/libraries/cass_cpp-driver/git2/cpp-driver/src/session.hpp:29:0, from /root/libraries/cass_cpp-driver/git2/cpp-driver/src/types.hpp:22, from /root/libraries/cass_cpp-driver/git2/cpp-driver/src/buffer_collection.cpp:19:
/root/libraries/cass_cpp-driver/git2/cpp-driver/src/logger.hpp: In member function 'int cass::Logger::init()':
/root/libraries/cass_cpp-driver/git2/cpp-driver/src/logger.hpp:40:59: error: no matching function for call to 'cass::AsyncQueue<cass::MPMCQueue<cass::Logger::LogMessage*> >::init(uv_loop_t*, cass::Logger* const, void (&)(uv_async_t*, int))'
   int init() { return log_queue_.init(loop(), this, on_log); }
                                                           ^
/root/libraries/cass_cpp-driver/git2/cpp-driver/src/logger.hpp:40:59: note: candidate is:
In file included from /root/libraries/cass_cpp-driver/git2/cpp-driver/src/event_thread.hpp:21:0,
                 from /root/libraries/cass_cpp-driver/git2/cpp-driver/src/session.hpp:20,
                 from /root/libraries/cass_cpp-driver/git2/cpp-driver/src/types.hpp:22,
                 from /root/libraries/cass_cpp-driver/git2/cpp-driver/src/buffer_collection.cpp:19:
/root/libraries/cass_cpp-driver/git2/cpp-driver/src/async_queue.hpp:34:7: note: int cass::AsyncQueue<Q>::init(uv_loop_t*, void*, uv_async_cb) [with Q = cass::MPMCQueue<cass::Logger::LogMessage*>; uv_loop_t = uv_loop_s; uv_async_cb = void (*)(uv_async_s*); uv_async_t = uv_async_s] <near match>
   int init(uv_loop_t* loop, void* data, uv_async_cb async_cb) {
       ^
/root/libraries/cass_cpp-driver/git2/cpp-driver/src/async_queue.hpp:34:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 3 from 'void(uv_async_t*, int) {aka void(uv_async_s*, int)}' to 'uv_async_cb {aka void (*)(uv_async_s*)}'
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/cassandra.dir/src/buffer_collection.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/cassandra.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2`

Comment: I've got the same issue on Windows.

Comment: I already fixed this error..

Comment: It seems that libuv has an update on its functions.. but is not yet supported by cassandra cpp-driver

Comment: What i did was changed the version of libuv to version libuv-0.10

Comment: @RoselynVerboDomingo would you mind adding that as an "answer" here so others who come along can learn the solution?

Comment: @BrianC done. thank you for your reminder. i'll do that if i encountered same cases in questions that i post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've already fixed this compile errors in Cassandra cpp-driver, by down-versioning libuv to  version libuv-0.10, the compile errors will be gone.

It seems that the latest updates for libuv is not yet supported by Cassandra cpp-driver.